# Prove Newton's method converges...

Tags: numerical-methods

How would you prove that Newton's Method applied to $f(x) = ax + b$ converges in one step? Would it be because the derivative of $f(x)$ is simply $a$?

Answer (score 4):

Write down the formula 
$$N(x) = x-\frac{f(x)}{f'(x)}$$
*for this specific function* and simplify.

In the course of that procedure, you will certainly use the fact that $f'(x)=a$.

Comment: So, it would just converge to b/a after one step, correct?

Comment: If the expression simplifies to just a constant then, yes, the convergence takes just one step. However, the constant should be the root, which is $-b/a$.